# Flash Display Issues Between Browsers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, browser

I'm having an issue with Flash apparently not displaying correctly and/or functionality being broken between different OSes and Browsers -- a problem I always thought was non-existent since the essence of Flash development was cross browser compatibility.

**The Problem:**
I'm working on a Flash module for a website that has quite a few layers of images being displayed to create a full image. When using the site on Windows in Chrome, FireFox, or Safari, everything works as intended. When using IE9, everything breaks completely and images disappear, transparency goes crazy and artifacts are all over the place; functionality even breaks. On a Mac, using either FireFox or Safari, everything displays correctly except for a handful of layers (3) that will not show up and appear to lock the browser up when the visibility is toggled true.

What this all boils down to are these two questions:

1. Are there known bugs with the way Flash is displayed in each browser that will require me to code in any specific way or avoid certain techniques?
2. Is this completely out of my hands to the point that I need to tell people to use only *x* operating system with *y* browsers?

**A Few Details:**
This is an AS3 project.

These are dynamically loaded .png files with transparency.

Several of the MovieClip instances that contain these loaded images have their BlendMode set to BlendMode.MULTIPLY, but otherwise it is a straight-forward display list of images.

The images that are being toggled on that cause problems are loaded when the other images are loading but simply turned off. They work perfectly fine using the Windows/Chrome|FireFox|Safari combinations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If you need more details please let me know what other information might help! Thanks in advance! 
-Jason

Edit: Here is the html/js embed code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Website</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />

<script src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script>
    var flashvars = {
    };
    var params = {
        menu: "false",
        scale: "noScale",
        allowFullscreen: "false",
        allowScriptAccess: "always",
        bgcolor: "",
        wmode: "direct" // can cause issues with FP settings & webcam
    };
    var attributes = {
        id:"Website"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "movie.swf", 
        "altContent", "960", "530", "11.2.0", 
        "expressInstall.swf", 
        flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
<style>
    html, body { height:100%; overflow:hidden; background-image:url('background.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; }
    body { margin:0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="altContent">
    <h1>Website</h1>
    <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Get Adobe Flash player</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please post the .html/.js code and your swf app? looks like a problem with embedding swf into the page. Also try changing the `wmode` property in your embed code

Comment: I'm also thinking in the area of `wmode`, this [link](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_) will learn you more... Try to change the `wmode` to see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Some blend modes are not supported when under gpu rendering, so as others said try playing with the wmode setting, also on windows the IE flash player is different then the chrome/firefox one. IE uses the active X player that might explain the different behavior between IE and FF/Chrome

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions folks. I tried changing the wmode but it still seems to be having problems (though slightly different ones).

@www0z0k - I will post the html/js but I can not post the actual swf unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Okay -- after checking the website from @www.creative-geeks.com, I tried the "window" wmode and that seemed to do the trick! Crossing my fingers that this will work on a Mac with Safari but it did fix the IE issue on windows.

Thanks a ton for the suggestion - I really appreciate the advice guys!

Comment: After some more testing there still seems to be problems when using Safari on the Mac. If anyone else has other suggestions please let me know -- anything at all would be helpful. I'm at my wits end with this problem! Thanks!

Comment: what are the problems? the swf is not displayed at all or it's not displayed correctly?